# How to pull out handler using module exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am building a node application, and trying to neatly organize my code. I wrote a serial module that imports the serial libs and handles the connection. My intention was to write a basic module and then reuse it over and over again in different projects as needed. The only part that changes per use is how the incoming serial data is handled. For this reason I would like to pull out following handler and redefine it as per the project needs. How can I use module exports to redefine only this section of the file?

I have tried added `myParser` to exports, but that gives me a null and I would be out of scope.

**Handler to redefine/change/overload for each new project**

```
myParser.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    //DO SOMETHING WITH DATA
});
```

Example usage: **main.js**

```
const serial = require('./serial');
const dataParser = require('./dataParser');
const serial = require('./serial');

//call connect with CL args
serial.connect(process.argv[2], Number(process.argv[3]))

serial.myParser.on('data',(data) => {
   //Do something unique with data
    if (dataParser.parse(data) == 0)
       serial.send('Error');
});
```

Full JS Module below **serial.js**

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const ReadLine = require('@serialport/parser-readline');
const _d = String.fromCharCode(13); //char EOL


let myPort = null;
let myParser = null;

function connect(port, baud) {
     let portName = port || `COM1`;
     let baudRate = baud || 115200;

     myPort = new SerialPort(portName, {baudRate: baudRate})
     myParser = myPort.pipe(new ReadLine({ delimiter: '\n'}))

     //Handlers
    myPort.on('open', () => {
        console.log(`port ${portName} open`)
    });

    myParser.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });

    myPort.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`port ${portName} closed`)
    });

    myPort.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('port error: ' + err)
    });
}

function getPorts() {
    let portlist = [];
    SerialPort.list((err, ports) => {
        ports.forEach(port => {
            portlist.push(port.comName)
        });
    })
    return portlist;
}

function send(data) {
    myPort.write(JSON.stringify(data) + _d, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
        }
        console.log(`${data} sent`);
    });
}

function close() {
    myPort.close();
}


module.exports = {
    connect, getPorts, send, close
}
```

Comment: Where is connect called?

Comment: @estus from the main.js. Edited code to reflect call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a module is used where a class or a factory would be appropriate. `myParser` cannot exist without `connect` being called, so it doesn't make sense to make it available as module property, it would be unavailable by default, and multiple `connect` calls would override it.

It can be a factory:

```
module.exports = function connect(port, baud) {
     let portName = port || `COM1`;
     let baudRate = baud || 115200;

     let myPort = new SerialPort(portName, {baudRate: baudRate})
     let myParser = myPort.pipe(new ReadLine({ delimiter: '\n'}))

     //Handlers
    myPort.on('open', () => {
        console.log(`port ${portName} open`)
    });

    myParser.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
    });

    myPort.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`port ${portName} closed`)
    });

    myPort.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('port error: ' + err)
    });

    function getPorts() {
        let portlist = [];
        SerialPort.list((err, ports) => {
            ports.forEach(port => {
                portlist.push(port.comName)
            });
        })
        return portlist;
    }

    function send(data) {
        myPort.write(JSON.stringify(data) + _d, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
            }
            console.log(`${data} sent`);
        });
    }

    function close() {
        myPort.close();
    }

    return {
        myParser, getPorts, send, close
    };
}
```

So it could be used like:

```
const serial = require('./serial');

const connection = serial(...);

connection.myParser.on('data',(data) => {
   //Do something unique with data
    if (dataParser.parse(data) == 0)
       connection.send('Error');
});
```